# Tensorflow inferences on Android, can't find 'Iterator' op. No OpKernel was registered to support Op

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Iterator' with these attrs.

I am trying to run a trained tensorflow model on an Android device.  The model I am trying to run on the android mobile device uses an Iterator operation in the inference graph.  I am trying to run this on a newly created Android Studio project.

I am using

- Android Studio 3.1.3
- Android NDK 14b
- Andorid SDK v28
- Bazel 0.14.1
- Tensorflow 1.8.0 (For training and for creating the .so and .jar files)

I generated a Tensorflow .jar file and .so file from Tensorflow using this bazel guide in the README https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/android The .so file size was 14.1 MB.

I added the .jar under libs directory of the Android Studio project, and added the .so file under the jniLibs/armeabi-v7a directory.  I got the following error after attempting to make an inference in the Android Studio applicaton.

```
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Checking to see if TensorFlow native methods are already loaded
E/art: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.contrib.android.RunStats.allocate() (tried Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate and Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate__)
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: TensorFlow native methods not found, attempting to load via tensorflow_inference
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded TensorFlow native methods (RunStats error may be ignored)
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Model load took 764ms, TensorFlow version: 1.8.0
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded model from 'file:///android_asset/laptop_frozen_graph_init_tables.pb'
E/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Failed to run TensorFlow inference with inputs:[batch_size, src_data], outputs:[index_to_string_Lookup]
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5769
                  Process: com.example.student.projecttest, PID: 6805
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Iterator' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
                    <no registered kernels>

                     [[Node: Iterator = Iterator[container="infer", output_shapes=[[?,?], [?]], output_types=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32], shared_name=""]()]]
                      at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
                      at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
                      at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:298)
                      at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:248)
                      at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:228)
                      at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:197)
                      at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:187)
                      at com.example.student.projecttest.MainActivity.translateToFrench(MainActivity.java:79)
                      at com.example.student.projecttest.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:42)
```

I also ran the tensorflow/python/tools/print_selective_registration_header tool to generate a ops_to_register.h file from the frozen .pb model, in the ops_to_register.h file you can see the Iterator ops

```
...
|| isequal(op, "GreaterEqual")
     || isequal(op, "HashTableV2")
     || isequal(op, "Identity")
     || isequal(op, "InitializeTableFromTextFileV2")
     || isequal(op, "Iterator")
     || isequal(op, "IteratorGetNext")
     || isequal(op, "Less")
     || isequal(op, "LessEqual")
     || isequal(op, "LogicalAnd")
     || isequal(op, "LogicalNot")
...
```

and

```
...
"LookupTableOp<lookup::HashTable<int64, string>, int64, string>",
"LookupTableOp<lookup::HashTable<string, int64>, string, int64>",
"IdentityOp",
"InitializeTableFromTextFileOp",
"IteratorHandleOp",
"IteratorGetNextOp",
"BinaryOp<CPUDevice, functor::less<int32>>",
...
```

So the ops_to_register.h file finds the ops

I tried using other bazel commands to see if it would include the correct operation:

```
bazel build -c opt --copt="-DSELECTIVE_REGISTRATION" --copt="-DSUPPORT_SELECTIVE_REGISTRATION" //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a
```

I ran this after moving the ops_to_register.h file to the tensorflow/core/framework folder.  Producing a 4.1 MB .so file

```
bazel build -c opt --copt=-D__ANDROID_TYPES_FULL__ //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a
```

This bazel command should include everything from the Tensorflow library I believe, this produced a 17.2 MB file.

I also tried adding this gradle file.

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+'
```

But it failed with the same error.

I can load TensorFlowInferenceInterface, get the graph through there and iterate through all the operations and their names fine, but it fails when making an inference.

To make sure that I could run the model by loading tensors and operations by name. I made a small Tensorflow script that can make predictions.

On TF Python script to run:

1. "init_all_tables" operation to initialize the tables.
2. "MakeIterator" operation which initializes the iterator (while feeding some text data and batch size).
3. "index_to_string_Lookup:0" tensor run to get the output.

On the android device using .run with any of these will throw this error.

```
Example: inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{"init_all_tables"});
```

will throw the same 'No OpKernel was registered' error mentioned previously.

So I assume the problem is in finding the Iterator op.

I also tried to change the BUILD file a bit to try as suggested here: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11804#issuecomment-318415228

When messing with the build file mentioned in that suggestion, it would throw an error at the very end when it was close to finishing, I believe I might have done it wrong.
I'm not too sure how to change the BUILD in the tensorflow/core/kernel if that's the way to go because the iterator files are in /tensorflow/core/lib/io/ directory and not under the kernel directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated